# UITableView + UITableViewCell when UISegmentedControl is pressed

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I want to ask a question about UITableViewCell.
Apparently, this is what I want to achieve.

I have a page where I display one question at one time. So, when the UISegmentedController on the top right is pressed, I display another question and so on.

please see the picture attached or here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/27303579/StackOverflow.jpg

[image: Question 1 to Question 3]

Note that I use UITableView (Group style) to display my question. The question text is actually the Section Header.

*All the questions come from Web Service.

My question is:

What should I do when the NEXT (TOP RIGHT CORNER) button is pressed ? What can I do to refresh my page ? Do I need to reuse the current UITableView or how ?

Thanks a lot for your help guys. I hope I make myself clear. really appreciate it !

Comment: What you're showing has a navigation controller with a 'Back' button, which suggests that these are separate view controllers being pushed (...or maybe it started with an entirely different controller).  On the other hand, the arrow beside the 'NEXT' arrow suggests some different navigation.  Can you clarify what's going on there?

Comment: The button on the Left top corner is to go back to Main Menu. 
However, the UISegmentedController which is on the right hand side, is used to go to next question or go back to the previous question. Do you have any suggestion Phillip ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the arrow is pressed you can update the data in whatever data structure you have that populates your table cells, and then call `[self.tableView reloadData]`. This will trigger the `UITableViewDataSource` functions again, using the data structure to repopulate your table. Of course, `cellForRowAtIndexPath` will need some handling so that it knows how to draw the cells based on what data they are supposed to display.

Comment: Wow. That is interesting. It is starting to get clear now.. Let me try it on the office on Monday ! Thanks Dima !